# Can not find Get-AzureSqlServerUpgrade commandlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

Can't find

```
Stop-AzureSqlServerUpgrade
Start-AzureSqlServerUpgrade
Get-AzureSqlServerUpgrade
```

commands required for scheduling an upgrade to SQL Database V12. How to install those commands.

Troubleshooting details

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Module Azure

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                        
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                        
Manifest   0.9.7      Azure                               {Add-AzureAccount, Add-AzureApplicati...



PS C:\Windows\system32> $Host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

`Get-AzureSqlDatabase` command works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

You need to switch to the new `AzureResourceManager` mode.

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
Get-Command Stop-AzureSqlServerUpgrade
```

## More Info

Azure PowerShell now come in two modes: `AzureServiceManagement` and `AzureResourceManager`. We change between these using [`Switch-AzureMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722470.aspx).

Some commandlets are only available in one mode. The `Stop-AzureSqlServerUpgrade` commandlet and its brethren are only available in the `AzureResourceManager` mode.

If you want to determine the current mode, you can run `Get-Module *azure*`. The output will look like this and include the `Name` of your current mode.

```
ModuleType   Version   Name                   ExportedCommands
----------   -------   ----                   ----------------
Manifest     0.9.7     AzureResourceManager   {Add-AlertRule ...}
```

If the `Name` is just `Azure`, then you are in the Service Manager mode.